# Create formula checkbox field

Tags: apex, custom-object, formula, formula-field

I am trying to create a formula checkbox type field on custom object, which gets checked if related list "Notes & Attachment" has any files uploaded to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this. There's no way a formula can reference child objects (with a few special exceptions for standard relationships). Instead, you could make a checkbox field, make it read-only, and update via a trigger when a note/attachment is added/deleted to a parent record.